# Check if values exist together in any 2 columns in dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this:

```
col_A  col_B  col_C
 A      B      NaN
 NaN    NaN    C
 NaN    B      C
 A      NaN    C
 A      NaN    C
```

I want to get tuples which show how many times values are present in any 2 columns. For eg: A and B both exist together in the first row of the dataframe, but are absent anywhere else together. Thus I should get a tuple like this:

```
('A','B',1).
```

Similarly A and C exist together in 2 rows. Thus the output should be like:

```
('A','C',2)
```

and similarly for any 2 columns. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use nested list comprehension with removing missing values with [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
from collections import Counter

c = Counter([tuple([y for y in x if pd.notnull(y)]) for x in df.values.tolist()])
print (c)
Counter({('A', 'C'): 2, ('A', 'B'): 1, ('C',): 1, ('B', 'C'): 1})
```

Or [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) for remove missing values, create tuples by [`GroupBy.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) and add [`value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html):

```
c = df.stack().groupby(level=0).apply(tuple).value_counts()
print (c)
(A, C)    2
(A, B)    1
(C,)      1
(B, C)    1
dtype: int64
```

Last add values to keys:

```
out = [i + (j,) for i, j in c.items()]
print (out)
[('A', 'B', 1), ('C', 1), ('B', 'C', 1), ('A', 'C', 2)]
```